# Can't get javascript to run on this page. (Working on all other pages)

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone tell me why javascript won't run on this page?

I have the same javascript file linked to other pages and it runs perfectly on them.
I've put a load of time into figuring out whats wrong but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/static/styles/adminStyles/style.css"" rel=stylesheet type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/static/js/SampleApp.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="navbar">
              <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="brand" href="https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/">RSVPme</a>
                  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">

                      <li><a href="https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/admin/create_event">Create Event</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/admin/manage_events">Manage Events</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/admin/manage_events">Bookings</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/admin/test"> Test</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
<div id="eventsTable" >
    <table class="manageEventsTable" >
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Guestlist</th>
            <th>Cheaplist</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Guestlist</th>

        </tr>
                    <tr>
                <td> <center> Propaganda Dublin - 24/08/13 </center> </td>
                <td> <center>24-08-2013 </center></td>
                <td> <center>0 </center></td>
                <td> <center>2 </center></td>
                <td> <center>
                                    <a class="deleteEvent" href='https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/admin/event/id/8' ><img src="https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/static/resources/delete.png" width = '20' height ='20'> </a>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td> <center>
                                    <a href='https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/admin/guestlist/id/8' ><img src="https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/static/resources/download.png" width = '20' height ='20'> </a>
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>

                    <tr>
                <td> <center> Propaganda Dublin - 31/8   </center> </td>
                <td> <center>31-08-2013 </center></td>
                <td> <center>0 </center></td>
                <td> <center>1 </center></td>
                <td> <center>
                                    <a class="deleteEvent" href='https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/admin/event/id/10' ><img src="https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/static/resources/delete.png" width = '20' height ='20'> </a>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td> <center>
                                    <a href='https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/admin/guestlist/id/10' ><img src="https://thepropaganda.co/dublin-app/static/resources/download.png" width = '20' height ='20'> </a>
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>


    </table>
</div>    

        <!------ jQuery box ---->
                <div id="confirmDialog" style="display: none;" > 
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;" >
                        Are you sure you want to delete the event?
                    </p>
                </br>
                </div>


        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: It would probably help people knowing what exactly is supposed to be working. And showing both pages, the one that work and the other.

Comment: BTW The `center` tag is not supported in HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you would see if you look at the error console, jQuery is not defined.